# Which language for games on Windows Phone/Android

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

What's difference between using say c# + XNA framework and using native C++ and direct3d/directx for apps/games WP.

And similar for Android, i.e you can use Java + JDK or you can I believe use objective C and OpenGl

Or of course you could use the Unity engine.

What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use framework. If you don't want to write a game 2 times. (or more if you decide to support more platforms). 
You cannot use objective C for android (it's for ios). 
I really recommend to use a framework.
It could be:
- unity3d [c#/js]
- cocos2d-x [c++] (open source)
- phonegap [html+js] (open source)
- libgdx [java] may support wp in future (it's great for android/ios)
- corona sdk [lua] may support wp in future too (easy scripting, less code than others and faster to learn).

I tested almost all of these frameworks and my best choice is libgdx for now. Friendly language (java), great support, open source, many updates, works great on ios. Cocos2d-x could be a good option too if you don't mind writing in c++. For now I'm testing unity3d :)

Each framework has some advantages and disadvantages, but it's still better than writing a game once more for each platform. And for example for android without framework you cannot write smooth and efficient game without using opengl or framework (which uses opengl though).

Comment: +1 for Frameworks usage, If you code your Game in any plateform, one by one, you re-use just 15% or your code for the other plateform ( you rewrite 85 % of your code)...
With a framework (I know Unity) You can create a game for all plateform and rewrite just 10% of your code to adjust your game in other plateform.

With last version of Unity, you can easy make a 2D game. And you can create a games for iOs, Android, WinPhone(8 not 7), PC, Linux, Mac, Web, and Xbox 360 / PS3 (with a large supplement to the tariff level) and, in few month(week?) X-One and PS4.

But, Is it not open source...